# Difficulty translating Spanish text from an entry for 1930 in Civil Guard records

Tags: identificación-de-término

I have this Spanish Civil Guard document that I am slowly working through for my Great Grandfather.

Here is one little section I am trying to transcribe:

[image]

So far, with some help, I have come up with:

> Con fecha 26 de Diciembre del año anterior, le fueron concedidos a este individuo 25 días de permiso para Cádiz y Osuna (Sevilla), de los cuales no hizo uso por haber manifestado XX convenion. Cumpliendo su compromiso en 3 de Agosto de 1930 solicito y le fue concedido por su primer jefe otro por el tiempo de 4 años por reunir las condiciones prevenidas, incluso la de utilidad y como comprenXX dicho en la R. O. C. de 11 de agosto de 1920 (C XXX n.º 195) pero en concepto de provisional hasta la aprobación definitiva del Excmo S. Director Gral del Cuerpo. Dicho compromiso da principio en 1º de Sepbre [Septiembre] de 1930 y lo terminará en 31 de agosto de 1934, disfrutando durante el mismo el premio mensual de 2750 ptas [pesetas]. Ten prueba de su conformidad firma el interesado la presente y testigo que suscriben = El interesado = Miguel Torres Jiménez, testigos El Gua D. Francisco Castellano Caballero = El Gua 1. Juan Mora Trigo = El Comandante Mayor Emilio Bararbas Selasco = Rubricados.

But it is not 100% correct and would approeciate advice. Once I have the Spanish correct I can then use DeepL to translate to English.

---

### Related Questions

- [Transcribing Spanish text (Title) of Civil Guard document and deciphering Job Title](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39379/28260)
- [Transcribing the various Assignments that my Great Grandfather had (as listed on his Civil Guard records)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39382/28260)
- [Difficulty translating Spanish text from an entry for 1905 in Civil Guard records](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39387/28260)
- [Difficulty translating Spanish text from an entry for 1906 in Civil Guard records](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39397/28260)
- [Difficulty translating Spanish text from an entry for 1906/1907 in Civil Guard records](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39402/28260)
- [Difficulty translating Spanish text for remaining 1904 entries in Civil Guard records](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39411/28260)

Comment: @Sisifo Thank you for your suggestions. They are very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Soy traductor profesional. Lo he transcrito, con un par de comas de más a usanza actual y unas notas del significado de ciertas abreviaciones y palabras. Las siglas R.O.C. me dieron batalla, pero al final encontré su posible significado. Las siglas C.H.n no encontré su significado. Otra nota es que 27.50 pesetas aparentemente tendrían un valor hoy de aproximadamente [47.34 dólares estadounidenses](https://www.usinflationcalculator.com/), valor al que llegué usando la referencia del valor histórico de la peseta y del calculador de inflación.
Que estés bien, cualquier duda, por aquí estoy.

> Con fecha 26 de diciembre del año anterior, se fueron concedidos a este individuo 25 días de permiso para Cádiz y Osuna (Sevilla), de los cuales no hizo uso por haber manifestado no le convenía. Cumpliendo su compromiso en 3 de agosto de 1930, solicitó y le fue concedido por su primer jefe, otro tiempo de 4 años por reunir las condiciones prevenidas, incluso la de utilidad y como comprendido en la R.O.C. [nota del transcriptor: Real Orden Circular?] de 11 de agosto de 1920 (C.H.n no. 195), pero en concepto de provisional hasta la aprobación definitiva del Excmo Sr. Director Gral. del Cuerpo [n. del t.: Excelentísimo Señor Director General del Cuerpo]. Dicho compromiso *da principio* en 1º de Sepbre [septiembre] de 1930 y lo terminará en 31 de agosto de 1934, disfrutando durante el mismo el premio mensual de [27.50 ptas.](https://www.bde.es/f/webbde/SES/Secciones/Publicaciones/PublicacionesSeriadas/DocumentosTrabajo/90/Fich/dt_9011.pdf) [pesetas]. Y en prueba de su conformidad, firma el interesado la presente y testigos que suscriben: El interesado, Miguel Torres Jiménez. Testigos: El Gua [guardia?] 2º Francisco Castellano Caballero. El Gua 1º Juan Mora Trigo. El Comandante Mayor Emilio Barailar Velasco. [Rubricados [con sello, firmado]](https://dle.rae.es/rubricar?m=form).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help with this. This document is 21 pages so I may be asking for more advise in time. But I am slightly confused. On 1st August 1990 the exchange rate was 1 GBP to 181 PTAS. This is why I read it as 2750. Even then that would be equal to £15 a month. So the figure 27.50 seems small?

Comment: No problem. I have a passion for translation and redaction. If I have time, I would be happy to help in your document. Regarding the exchange rate of GBP, did you take into consideration inflation from 1930 and the exchange rate at that time? And second, if you notice, there is an apostrophe between 27 and 50 that doesn't seem to be accidental. That makes me think that "premio" (which transliterated means "prize") translates to either prize or bonus, not salary or regular monthly pay.

Comment: A mí [me pareció leer](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/18342/transcribing-and-translating-civial-guard-document-from-spain?noredirect=1#comment27434_18342) _da principio_ en lugar de _lo principió_. El significado es el mismo, claro está.

Comment: I think "condedido" might be "concedido". The former was rasing as incorrect in my Word Processor.

Comment: tienen, razón, lo corregí :D

Comment: @freethinker36, las siglas a las que te refieres como (C.H.n no. 195), me parecen (**C.Q.** no. 195) (I can't write comments yet.)

Comment: I think this fragment is: _en la R.O.C. de 11 de agosto de 1920 (C.L. no. 195)_. Indeed, R.O.C. stands for _Real Orden Circular_. C.L. stands for _Colección Legislativa_. The cited decree can be consulted [here](https://bibliotecavirtual.defensa.gob.es/BVMDefensa/es/publicaciones/verNumero.do?idNumero=47989) (page 390 of the PDF file).

Comment: I have just updated my note for 1930 to use **C.L** instead of **C.H**.

Comment: @gparis I have only stumbled on your comment here and did not realise there are links to the C. L. information. I need to look. Thanks.