# Transcribing the various Assignments that my Great Grandfather had (as listed on his Civil Guard records)

Tags: identificación-de-término

My work continues in trying to transcribe my Great Grandfathers Civil Guard record (from Spain). My queries below relate to page two of the document where it details in a list the various assignments he had and for how long.

---

## Background

On page one of the document it stated that he was decreed as a soldier on **23rd March 1902** and that he was commissioned into the **caja de quintos de Osuna (Osuna fifth corps)** on **1st August 1902**. It also stated that he subsequently transferred from the **Comandª Artillería de Menorca (Artillery Headquarters of menorca)** to the **Civil Guard** on **1st September 1906**.

So those are the key dates.

---

### SEGUNDA DIVISION

[image]

I have tried to transcribe the above set of data. here is my attempt:

> - 1 Agosto 1902 / Soldado en Caja XXX / - - -
> - 3 Marzo 1904 / XXX / 1a 9m 28d
> - 1 Enero 1906 / XXX / - 8m -
> - 1 Sepbre 1906 / Gia Civil de 2a Clase / 25a 10m
> - 1 Julio 1932 / Gia Civil de 1a Clase / 3a 7m
>
> Total de servicios efectivos hasta fin Enero 1936 / 31a 10m 28d

The key dates are there (**1st August 1902** and **1st September 1906**).

I can't quite make out the complete list of his assignments though as you can see. But the sum total of 31 years, 10 months and 28 days works out.

But you might see somethign else I have overlooked.

---

### CUARTA SUBDIVISION

[image]

This is the other section on the page with another list of his assignments.

So far I have:

> - En la Caja de XXX de Osuna. XXX / - - -
> - En el XX Boñ de Artillería de Plaza / - 5m 28d
> - En la Comanda de Artillería de Menorca / 2a - -
> - En la Guia Civil / 29a 5m -

Again, the totals seem to work out correctly but I can't quite make out the actual text of his assignments as described there.

---

#### Side Note

I have a photo ID Card of my Great Grandfather for when he was in the Civil Guard (1st Class) but it is dated in 1942. But all of these records seem to only go up to 1936.

I am grateful for clarifications on the correct terms of his assignments as detailed here.

---

### Related questions

- [Difficulty translating Spanish text from an entry for 1930 in Civil Guard records](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39375/28260)
- [Transcribing Spanish text (Title) of Civil Guard document and deciphering Job Title](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39379/28260)
- [Difficulty translating Spanish text from an entry for 1905 in Civil Guard records](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39387/28260)
- [Difficulty translating Spanish text from an entry for 1906 in Civil Guard records](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39397/28260)
- [Difficulty translating Spanish text from an entry for 1906/1907 in Civil Guard records](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39402/28260)
- [Difficulty translating Spanish text for remaining 1904 entries in Civil Guard records](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39411/28260)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First period for both documents seems to be "Soldado en Caja [de Reclutas de Osuna] 1 año 7 ms (meses) y 2 ds (días)." The last word is difficult to read, but probably makes reference to the fact that it seems that such period is not actually used to compute service years (note also that the numbers are not in the columns).

"Caja de Reclutas" would be the administrative services of the recruiting process, Osuna being a town in Spain.

---

The 2nd period in the "Segunda subdivisión" could read "Volun(tario) en activo", but I am not 100% sure. It would mean that he was no longer doing his military service but had passed into the professional army. That would explain why the first period (which would have been his military service) was not computed in the total time.

---

The 3rd period in the "Segunda subdivisión" reads "Cabo por elección", lit. "Caporal by election." "By election" refers to how he got promoted, the page of the [Spanish Ministry of Defense](http://www.reclutamiento.defensa.gob.es/como-ingresar/suboficiales/que-ofrecemos/desarrolla-futuro/) just explains that:

> Se producirá entre aquellos militares más capacitados e idóneos para acceder al empleo superior.
> Se asciende por elección al empleo de suboficial mayor.

Basically, he was hand-picked to be promoted to corporal instead of getting the promotion by other means (seniority, or a more formal selection process with several candidates going through exams or a similar system).

---

The 3rd period in "Cuarta subdivisión" would be "En el 2X (¿2o?) Bón de Artillería de Plaza", or "En el 2X (¿2o?) Batallón de Artillería de Plaza". [This page](http://foro.elgrancapitan.org/viewtopic.php?p=844027) lists the existence of a "Batallón de Artillería de Plaza" at Mahón (Minorca), but it does not give its number.

Comment: Thanks, most informative. I can now clearly see the duration stated as you indicate. And I do think that other reference is 2o. Any thoughts on the second period in the Segundo Subdivision?

Comment: Thanks for your update for period 2. The only other think not quite making sense is the periods referred to in the bottom list compared to top. The civil guard makes sense (25.10 + 3.7 = 29.5). But the other totals don't seem to match.

Comment: They do match. 1.9.28 + 0.8.0 = 1.17.28 = 2.5.28

Comment: I see, but in that list is shows 0.5.28 and 2.0.0 (which I admit is a total of 2.5.28). Just can't get my ahead around why that 2.5.28 period is broken up differently. I am missing something in my understanding of the data listed.

Comment: FYI. I am trying to transcribe some of the subsequent notes on pages 3 and 4. Whilst I can't work out all the text at this time it is clear that it refers to Cadiz and Mahón in Menorca. Well done. Thanks! After I can done as much as I can for pages 3 and 4 I will ask a new question to the community.

Comment: FYI. The 1906 entry explains more about his promotion. This is all interestiung. But my transcribing is incomplete. Thanks again!