# Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1932

Tags: identificación-de-término

There is one note for 1932 in my great-grandfathers Civil Guard records. This note relates to his promotion to the 1st Civil Guard Class as was documented here ([Transcribing the various Assignments that my Great Grandfather had (as listed on his Civil Guard records)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39382/28260)).

The note:

[image]

I have made out most of the transcription:

> En la revista de Julio año marginal y según por puesta aprobada xxx
> Sr. [Señor] Coronel Subinspectora del Cuerpo ha sido promanada este
> individuo al empleo de Guardia de 1º clase para su misma Compañía y
> finió el año en el puesto de Puente Genil.
>
> El Comandante Mayor

Translation so far:

> In the review of July of the marginal year and according to the
> approved order of xxx Mr. Colonel Sub-Inspector of the Corps, this
> individual has been promoted to the position of 1st class Guard for
> the same Company and ended the year in the post of Puente Genil.
>
> The Major Commander

I can't quite make out that prefix just before **Sr.**. It does not look like **Excmo.** or one of the other abbreviations to me that have been used in the document.

I was hoping there would be an officio D.O or something relating to his move to the 1st class but sadly not.

---

#### Updated Translation

This translation is based on the answer provided which is now much better:

> In the July review of the marginal year and according to a proposal
> approved by the Colonel Sub-Inspector of the Corps, this individual
> was promoted to the rank of Guard 1st [first] class for the same
> Company and ended the year at the Puente Genil post.
>
> The Major Commander

---

#### Remaining Notes

I appreciate that a lot of work has been done on these notes for me over the last few days. Thank you. Based on the knowledge I have gained to understand the writing I am now able to do some of the remaining ones. Below is a summary of what is left for me to discuss with you:

- [1933 (1 note)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39537/28260)
- [1934 (1 note)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39539/28260)
- [1935 (1 note)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39542/28260)

I need to go through these notes again myself before I ask.

Then we will be completed!

Comment: This is like a series to me, and I guess others, and am enjoying it a lot. I hope there is a second season after summer ;-)

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' :) Well, if I ever manage to get my grandfathers papers (he was in the military - I know that much) then maybe there will be a second season. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, it looks like this (bold for the differences with your proposal):

> En la revista de Julio año marginal y según **propuesta** aprobada **por** el Sr. [Señor] Coronel **Subinspector** del Cuerpo ha sido **promovido** este individuo al empleo de Guardia de **1.ª** [primera] clase para su misma Compañía y finió el año en el puesto de Puente Genil.

Where '[promover](https://dle.rae.es/promover)' is a verb that stands for *promote*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and additional background information!

Answer (score 0):

No sé mucho sobre la transcripción de un documento. Pero si necesita algún tipo de ayuda con la escritura, puede obtener ayuda en línea. También puede echar un vistazo a un [gran artículo para leer](https://ejemplius.com/muestras-de-ensayos/senor-de-las-moscas/). Veo que hay varias plataformas de escritura disponibles. Ellos pueden ayudarte fácilmente con lo que necesites (si está relacionado con la escritura).

Comment: Bienvenido/a a [Spanish.se]. Te recomiendo visitar las secciones de [tour] y [help] para entender un poco mejor la filosofía de este sitio. Échale también un vistazo a otras preguntas y respuestas. Procura responder _realmente_ a la pregunta y recuerda que el formato adecuado puede servir para hacer tu respuesta más fácil de leer y entender.