# Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1933

Tags: identificación-de-término

There is one note for 1933 in my great-grandfathers Civil Guard records.

This is the note:

[image]

This is the transcribed text so far:

> Con arreglo al Dechelo de la Presidencia del Gobierno fecha 22 Abril
> 1931 [D. O. no 90] firmo la promesa de fidelidad a la Republica que en
> aquel se premiere. Prestando sus servicios en el puesto de Puente
> Genil finió el año.
>
> El Jefe del Detall

There are a couple of words there that I have struggled with (e.g. **Dechelo**). And I think it has a reference to a [D.O. no. 90](http://www.bibliotecavirtualdefensa.es/BVMDefensa/es/catalogo_imagenes/grupo.do?path=13950). I can't quite make out if the abbreviation is actually **D.O.** but I was able to find a bulletin with the right number **90**. I am not sure though which information in this document relates to this note.

The translation I have so far is:

> In accordance with the Decree of the Presidency of the Government
> dated 22 April 1931 [D. O. No. 90] I sign the promise of loyalty to
> the Republic which is awarded therein. Serving at the Puente Genil
> post at the end of the year.
>
> The Chief of the Detall

Thanks for your assistance once again.

---

#### Updated Translation

Here is the translation based on the answer provided:

> In accordance with the Decree of the Presidency of the Government
> dated 22 April 1931 [D. O. No. 90], he signed the promise of loyalty
> to the Republic provided for therein. Serving at the Puente Genil post
> at the end of the year.
>
> The Chief of the Detall

---

#### Linked Bulletin

I transcribed / translated the linked bulletin snapshot in the answer:

- Spanish

> Art. 6.o Cuando el Ministerio de la Guerra lo determine, las
> autoridades regionales, darán las ordenes e instrucciones precisas
> para demandar la promesa a las clases e individuos de tropa de los
> Cuerpos, centros o dependencias de la región. A ello queda igualmente
> obligado el personal, con asimilación militar, que sirve en fábricas,
> talleres, parques y laboratorios, aunque no estén considerados como
> clases e individuos de tropa.
>
> Dado en Madrid a veintidós de abril de mil novecientos treinta y uno.

- English

> Art. 6. o When the Ministry of War so determines, the regional
> authorities shall give the necessary orders and instructions to demand
> the pledge from the troop classes and individuals of the Corps,
> centres or dependencies of the region. Personnel, with military
> assimilation, who serve in factories, workshops, parks and
> laboratories, although they are not considered as troop  classes and
> individuals, shall also be obliged to do so.
>
> Given in Madrid on the twenty-second day of April of the year one
> thousand nine hundred and thirty-one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestions

> Con arreglo al **Decreto** de la Presidencia del Gobierno fecha 22 Abril
> 1931 [D. O. no 90] firm**ó** la promesa de fidelidad a la Republica que en
> aquel se **previene**. Prestando sus servicios en el puesto de Puente
> Genil finió el año.
>
> El Jefe del Detall

The little accent mark in **firmó** will change your translation.

---

This is the article that affected your great grandfather (page 2 of the PDF document you found)

[image: Art.6 D.O.90 1931]

The [Second Spanish Republic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Spanish_Republic) began the 14th April 1931. As pointed by @fedorqui, it was probably one of the first decrees signed by the new goverment.

Comment: I was about to post the exact same suggestions. Good one. May be good to explain that [the II República was proclaimed on April 14, 1931](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proclamación_de_la_Segunda_República_Española), so this was probably one of the first laws to be signed by the new rulers.

Comment: Thank you both for the answer and clarifications!

Comment: I decided to translate the linked bulletin bit for my benefit. :)

Comment: @AndrewTruckle that an interesting insight. In fact, one of the big problems of the Second Spanish Republic had to do with loyalty of the army to the government, so this decree is quite relevant to what came next.