# Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1934

Tags: identificación-de-término

There is one note for 1934 in my great-grandfathers Civil Guard records.

This is the note (split over 2 pages):

[image]

[image]

I can see that this is the final time that his enlistment is renewed. So I tried to extract words I was not sure of from previous notes. But there is a handful of issues:

> Con motivo de la xxx ganiracion  dada a las unidades del  Tercio en 1º
> de Enero año marginal paso este individuo a xxx este xxx a la 6ª
> Compañía de la Comandancia de Córdoba confirmado en el mismo puesto.
> Cumpliendo su compromiso en 31 de Agosto año del margen solicito y le
> fue concedido, por su Primer jefe otro por el tiempo de 1 año 4 meses
> y 4 días. Por reunir las condiciones prevenidas incluso de la utilidad
> y como comprendido en la Orden circular de 11 de Agosto de 1920 (C. L.
> nº 195) pero en concepto de provisional hasta la aquebracen definitivo
> del Excmo. Señor Subinspector General del Cuerpo [. Dicho] compromiso
> da xxx en 1º de Septiembre de 1934 y lo terminara en 4 de Enero de
> 1936. Y en prueba il su conformidad firma el interesado la presente nota con los testigos que suscriben.
>  El interesado = Miguel Torres
> Jimenez
>  Testigos =
>  El Gua [Guardia 2º] = Juan Bamos Mera
> El Gua [Guardia 2º] = xxx
>  El Comandante jefe del Detall =
> firma
>  Reubicados
>  El copia
>  El Comandante Jefe del Detall

---

#### Updated Translation

Translation based on answer:

> On the occasion of the reorganisation of the units of the Tercio on
> 1st January of the marginal year, this individual became a member of
> the 6th Company of the Cordoba Command and was confirmed in the same
> post. Fulfilling his commitment on 31st August of the year in
> question, he requested and was granted, by his First Commander,
> another for a period of 1 year, 4 months and 4 days, as he met the
> conditions laid down, including that of usefulness and as included in
> the Circular Order of 11th August 1920 (C. L. nº 195) but on a
> provisional basis until the definitive approval of His Excellency the
> Inspector General of the Corps. This commitment begins on 1st
> September 1934 and will end on 4th January 1936. And in proof of his
> agreement, the interested party signs this note with the undersigned
> witnesses.
>  The interested party = Miguel Torres Jimenez
> Witnesses =
>  The 2nd Guardsman = Juan Baños Mera
>  The 2nd
> Guardsman = Tomás Mayorga García
>  The Chief in Command of the
> Detall = signature
>  All initialled
>  
>  The copy
>  The Chief
> in Command of the Detall

So my great-grandfather knew in advance that his time with the Civil Guard was going to come to an end in January 1936.

Comment: My suggestions match the ones offered by fedorqui. Just add that it's "Todos Rubricados" instead of "Reubicados", the first signing guard was "Juan Baños Mera" and the second  "Tomás Mayorga García".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see this (I am using **bold** for the differences with your proposal):

> Con motivo de la **reorganización** dada a las unidades del Tercio en 1º de Enero año marginal pas**ó** este individuo a **pertenecer** a la 6ª Compañía de la Comandancia de Córdoba **confirmando** en el mismo puesto. Cumpliendo su compromiso en 31 de Agosto año del margen **solicitó** y le fue concedido, por su Primer jefe otro por el tiempo de 1 año 4 meses y 4 días, por reunir las condiciones prevenidas incluso **el** de utilidad y como comprendido en la Orden circular de 11 de Agosto de 1920 (C. L. nº 195) pero en concepto de provisional hasta la **aprobación** **definitiva** del Excmo. Señor **Inspector** General del Cuerpo. Dicho compromiso da **principio** en 1º de Septiembre de 1934 y lo **terminará** en 4 de Enero de 1936. Y en prueba **de** su conformidad firma el interesado la presente nota con los testigos que suscriben.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have added a translation to the question with my observations.