# Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1935

Tags: identificación-de-término

Alas, we come to the final note for 1935 where I appreciate some help in transcribing and translating my great-grandfathers life from enlisting in the army when he was 20 to his retirement in 1936.

You have all helped me along this journey and I have gained an insight into my great-grandfather (who was just a face on a photo until now).

I have built a map in Google of the locations he was stationed and maybe one day I can walk his steps!

Anyway - I digress - just wanted to say thank you to you all for your help!

---

Here is the note for 1935 which is split over two pages and I find some of the writing quite hard!

[image]

[image]

I have attempted to transcribe the text:

> El dia 2 de Abril año marginal, xxx este individuo y xxx Madrid en xxx
> de 29 dias de servicio por xxx xxx, concedidos xxx el Excmo. Señor
> Inspecto General  del Cuerpo, segregando a xxx fuerte el dia 30 del
> mismo una xxx disfrutada. Cunpliendo la edad reglamentaria en 4 de
> Enero próximo y recinende en fin del mismo. 31 año 10 mes y 28  dias
> de xxx xxx se le propone para el retiro con el 80% y haba xxx mensual
> de 217’33 pesetas xxx xxx comprendido en la xxx de 31 de Diciembre de
> 1921 [D.O. no. 1 ? Enero de 1922 (el xxx xxx a xxx de xxx xxx por la
> Jefe xxx de xxx de Cordoba por xxx su residencia en Puente Genil il
> dicha provincia.
>
> Cordoba 4 Deciembre 1935
>
> El Jefe del Detall

I can't quite make out the D.O references so have not been able to provide a link.

Thanks again for your help! Muchas gracias!

---

#### Translation

This is the translation based on the answer provided:

> On the 2nd of April of the marginal year, this individual left for
> Madrid to take 29 days leave for personal matters, granted by the
> Inspector General of the Corps, returning to his post on the 30th of
> the same month once he had taken his leave. Having reached the statutory
> age on the 4th of January and having completed 31 years, 10 months and
> 28 days of effective service at the end of the same, he is proposed
> for retirement with 80% and a monthly pension of 217.33 pesetas as he
> is included in the Law of 31st December 1921 [D.O. no. 1 of 1st
> January 1922 (which will be paid to him from the following February by
> the Cordoba Tax Office as his residence is in Puente Genil in the
> aforementioned province.
>
> Cordoba 4 November 1935
>
> The Chief of Detail

I think it is very clear. Just got to locate the **Law** referred to in the [bulletin](http://www.bibliotecavirtualdefensa.es/BVMDefensa/es/catalogo_imagenes/grupo.do?path=11985).

Comment: I now think the D.O. might be 1 Enero 1922. http://www.bibliotecavirtualdefensa.es/BVMDefensa/es/catalogo_imagenes/grupo.do?path=11985 Not sure.

Comment: I'm not sure if you have it yet but I've located the part of the law applied to your ancestor and updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I'm curious, where are you putting / publishing the whole compendium of the notes?

Comment: @SergioVelasquez I have put it all into two Word documents (English / Spanish) with links to the stack exchange questions. I have also printed out some of the reference material. It is my intention to share what we have researched with my mother in the first instance.  At the moment I was not planning of "publushing" as such, apart from attaching to my family tree.

Comment: That's a very nice gesture :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestions (plus the ones suggested by @gparis)

> El dia 2 de Abril año marginal, **salió** este individuo **para** Madrid en **uso**
> de 29 días de **permiso** por **asuntos propios**, concedidos **por** el Excmo. Señor
> Inspecto**r** General del Cuerpo, **regresando** a **su puesto** el dia 30 del
> mismo una **vez disfrutados**. Cu**m**pliendo la edad reglamentaria en 4 de
> Enero próximo y **reuniendo** en fin del mismo 31 año 10 mes y 28 días de
> **efectivo servicio** se le propone para el retiro con el 80% y **haber** **pasivo** mensual de
> 217’33 pesetas **por hallarse** comprendido en la **Ley** de 31 de Diciembre de
> 1921 [D.O. no. 1 **del 1** Enero de 1922 (el cual **le será abonado** a **partir** de **Febrero siguiente** por la
> **Delegación** de **Hacienda** de C**ó**rdoba por **fijar** su residencia en Puente Genil **de**
> dicha provincia.
>
> C**ó**rdoba 4 Noviembre 1935
>
> El Jefe del Detall

---

The law mentioned is in the first page of the linked document

[image: The Law]

If we replace the idem and the id in the line that was applied to you great-grandparent, we got

> A los treinta (30) años de servicios efectivos en el Cuerpo, el ochenta por ciento (80%) de su haber

Comment: Two suggestions to complete the transcription: 1) **haber pasivo**, 2) I think the date is **4 Noviembre 1935**, the capital letter is different from other capital D's in the same note.

Comment: @gparis You are probably correct because there is a second note for 1935: *En el puesto de Puente Genil prestando sus servicios finió el año.*

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have added my translation and observations. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the update to your answer with bulletin info.

Comment: I just updated my translation as I noticed it said *returning to his post on the 30th of the same **day***. It should have been **month**.

Comment: My great-grandfather had 3 sons - all passed away - but one of them died around 1936. I don't have the details. All I know is that he was in the army (or something) and died young when he got shot. I have wondered if this note stating "personal business" was related to this. But we will most likely never know. I will try to do some more digging. 