# Difficulty translating Spanish text from an entry for 1906 in Civil Guard records

Tags: identificación-de-término

This is my ongoing efforts (with grateful assistance) at transcribing, translating and understanding my Great Grandfathers Civil Guard records.

### Background

We already know from this [answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/39384/28260) about page 2 of this document that my Great Grandfather was handpicked as a Coporal (dated 1 January 1906). To quote:

> Basically, he was hand-picked to be promoted to corporal instead of
> getting the promotion by other means (seniority, or a more formal
> selection process with several candidates going through exams or a
> similar system).

This entry for 1906 is related to this event:

[image]

I have been working on transcribing this text over the last two days and so far I have come up with:

> Según nombramiento aprobado por el **Sr.** Coronel 1er Jefe de la
> Comandancia, el individuo **contenido** en esta filiación fue ascendido a
> Cabo para la 2a Batería **cuya variación** de **clase** y pase de Batería tuvo lugar en
> la revista de Enero y con fecha 1o del mismo. Por disposición del **Sr.**
> Coronel 1er Jefe de la Comandancia de 27 de Enero **tomó** la
> **denominación** de 1a Batería --- a que **pertenece** el individuo **contenido** en
> esta filiación.
>
> En la revista del mes de Septiembre y con fecha de hoy **será** baja el
> individuo contenido en esta filiación en su Batería y Comandancia por
> pase a la de la Guardia Civil de Sevilla en clase de guardia 2o de
> Infantería a la que ha **sido** destinado **por** circular de la Dirección
> General de dicho Instituto de 22 de Agosto **(D. O. n<sup>o</sup> 181)** habiendo
> permanecido desde primero de año de guarnición en esta Plaza hasta el
> 1o de Mayo que marcho a Palma con **objeto** de **sufrir examen, regresando** a
> esta el día 4 del mismo y **siguió** de guarnición hasta la fecha de su baja.
> **Va satisfecho** de cuantos haberes le han correspondido y durante su
> permanencia en el servicio ha observado buena conducta.

As you can see, there are a few words that I can't quite make out. Once we have the transcribed texts correct I can move on to the translations.

I appreciate ongoing direction in completing the transcribing for this information.

Question: Does anyone know what **(D. O. W. 181)** might be referring to?

---

### Update 1

Incorporated the suggestions from the first answer provided:

- cuya
- variación
- clase
- sido

---

### Update 2

Incorporated the suggestions from the second answer provided:

- contenido
- Sr.
- denominación
- pertenece
- objeto
- sufrir
- examen
- regresando
- siguió
- Va satisfecho

That leaves one word not accounted for. I wondered if it was **por**?

> I don't know what's the meaning of (D.O.W 181) but I don't think that the last letter is a W. There are very few words in Spanish beginning with w.

Here it is zoomed in:

[image]

I now think that the abbreviation might be **(D. O. n 181)** with a lowercase letter following. Actually, I think that abbreviation is:

**(D. O. n<sup>o</sup> 181)**

The abbreviation is now **confirmed**. The next note for 1906 refers to it again, like this:

[image]

---

### Update 3

I thought that the missing word might be:

> Coronel 1er Jefe de la Comandancia de 27 de Enero tomó la denominación
> de 1a Batería **la á** que pertenece el individuo contenido en esta
> filiación.

If it is right, then the translation doesn't sound good to me:

> Colonel 1st Chief of the Command of 27 January took the name of the
> 1st Battery to which the individual contained in this affiliation
> belongs.

---

### Update 4

I also tried:

> Por disposición del Sr. Coronel 1er Jefe de la Comandancia de 27 de
> Enero tomó la denominación de 1a Batería **locá** a que pertenece el
> individuo contenido en esta filiación.

But I still end up with the same English, which doesn't seem correct to me. Looking at the letters and other handwriting it looks like  **locá**.

---

### Translation

Either way, using the current transcribed text I have come up with this translation:

> According to the appointment approved by the 1st Chief Colonel of the
> Command, the individual in this affiliation was promoted to Corporal
> for the 2nd Battery, whose change of class and transfer to the Battery
> took place in the review of January and on the 1st of the same. By
> order of the 1st Colonel Commander-in-Chief of the Command on 27th
> January, it was given the name of 1st Battery --- to which the
> individual in this affiliation belongs.
>
> In the review of the month of September and with today's date, the
> individual contained in this affiliation will be discharged from his
> Battery and Command by passing to that of the Civil Guard of Seville
> in the class of 2nd Infantry guard to which he has been assigned by
> circular of the General Directorate of the said Institute of 22 August
> (D. O. n<sup>o</sup> 181) having remained from the first of the year in garrison
> in this Fort until the 1st of May when he left for Palma in order to
> undergo an examination, returning to this on the 4th of the same and
> continued in garrison until the date of his discharge. He is satisfied
> with all his pay and during his time in the service he has observed
> good conduct.

For your info, the note is dated 31 Agosto 1906 (for context). The translation is getting there but not quite right.

---

### Related questions

- [Difficulty translating Spanish text from an entry for 1930 in Civil Guard records](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39375/28260)
- [Transcribing Spanish text (Title) of Civil Guard document and deciphering Job Title](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39379/28260)
- [Transcribing the various Assignments that my Great Grandfather had (as listed on his Civil Guard records)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39382/28260)
- [Difficulty translating Spanish text from an entry for 1905 in Civil Guard records](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39387/28260)
- [Difficulty translating Spanish text from an entry for 1906/1907 in Civil Guard records](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39402/28260)
- [Difficulty translating Spanish text for remaining 1904 entries in Civil Guard records](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39411/28260)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, let me fill in some blanks and fix some of your guesses

> Según nombramiento aprobado por el **Sr.** (Señor) Coronel 1er Jefe de la
> Comandancia, el individuo **contenido** en esta filiación fue ascendido a
> Cabo para la 2ª Batería **cuya variación** de **clase** y pase de Batería tuvo lugar en
> la revista de Enero y con fecha 1º del mismo. Por disposición del **Sr.**
> Coronel 1er Jefe de la Comandancia de 27 de Enero **tomó** la
> **denominación** de 1a Batería --- a que **pertenece** el individuo **contenido** en
> esta filiación.
>
> En la revista del mes de Septiembre y con fecha de hoy será baja el
> individuo contenido en esta filiación en su Batería y Comandancia por
> pase a la de la Guardia Civil de Sevilla en clase de guardia 2º de
> Infantería a la que ha **sido** destinado **por** circular de la Dirección
> General de dicho Instituto de 22 de Agosto (D. O. nº 181) habiendo
> permanecido desde primero de año de guarnición en esta Plaza hasta el
> 1º de Mayo que marchó a Palma con **objeto** de **sufrir examen**, **regresando** a
> esta el día 4 del mismo y **siguió** de guarnición hasta la fecha de su baja.
> **Va satisfecho** de cuantos haberes le han correspondido y durante su
> permanencia en el servicio ha observado buena conducta.

**D.O. número 181** means Diario Oficial (del Ministerio de la Guerra) número 181 - *Official Bulletin of the Ministry of War #181* - You can find such issue of the bulletin for [download](http://www.bibliotecavirtualdefensa.es/BVMDefensa/es/catalogo_imagenes/grupo.do?path=7524) in [the web of Biblioteca Virtual de Defensa](https://bibliotecavirtual.defensa.gob.es/BVMDefensa/es/inicio/inicio.do) (Main site). It was dated 25th August of 1906.
The Search Engine can be found [here](http://www.bibliotecavirtualdefensa.es/BVMDefensa/es/publicaciones/listar_numeros.do?busq_mes=11&busq_infoArticulos=true&busq_dia&busq_anyo=1906).

I've found your great grandfather's name in page 9 of the PDF document.

[image: D.O número 181]

Probably you'll find his promotion to Guardia 1ª in another later issue.

I think that you have a good translation so far, aside of the missing word.
Also I believe that "Fort" is not a good translation for "Plaza" in this context. In Spanish we have got the word "Fuerte" used for military purposes and it's diferent from "Plaza" in this context. In the document it means "Military Location" or "Military Premises". It can be a fort, a fortress, a castle, a building, ... It should exist a specific word in English used in equivalent military documents. Sorry if I misdirected you in my answer to your previous post.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my answer with your suggestions and the current translation. It is nearly correct I think. But the final sentence in the first paragraph needs completion.

Comment: I now know that the abbreviation is (D. O. número 181). As to what it stands for … hhm.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle I've updated my post with very relevant discoveries :-)

Comment: Wow - now that is exciting indeed. Thank you for your efforts with that, I will show my mum. :) As for "Plaza", what if we agree on "Military Base"? That is a general military term: https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Military+base#:~:text=Army%20base%20A%20base%20or%20group%20of%20installations,Army%20has%20operating%20responsibility.%20See%20also%20base%20complex.

Comment: I have a query about his being in the 2nd / 4th battery etc. but I will ask that separately after I have more context.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle "Military Base" is a good choice to understand the text, that is the main goal, I guess. It lack somehow the sense of archaic burocratic military jargon present in the original document but I think that it's not so relevant.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle You're welcome. Glad to help. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I let you here what i could understand:

Coronel 1er Jefe de la Comandancia, el individuo continuado en esta filiación fue ascendido a Cabo para la 2a Batería **cuya variación de clase** y pase de batería tuvo lugar en la revista de Enero y con fecha 1o del mismo.

En la revista del mes de Septiembre y con fecha de hoy será **baja** el individuo contenido en esta filiación en su Batería y Comandancia por pase a la de la Guardia Civil de Sevilla en clase de guardia 2o de Infantería a la que ha sido por *

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my question to include your suggested text in **bold**.