# Confusion about transfers to different Battery assignments - as contained in Civil Guard records

Tags: identificación-de-término

I have a question about this text:

> 1906: Según nombramiento aprobado por el Sr. Coronel 1er Jefe de la
> Comandancia, el individuo contenido en esta filiación fue ascendido a
> Cabo para la 2a Batería cuya variación de clase y pase de Batería tuvo
> lugar en la revista de Enero y con fecha 1o del mismo. Por disposición
> del Sr. Coronel 1er Jefe de la Comandancia de 27 de Enero tomó la
> denominación de 1a Batería --- a que pertenece el individuo contenido
> en esta filiación.

This is my understanding:

- 1904 - 2nd Battery (Mahon)
- 1905 - Transferred to 4th Battery (Mahon)
- 1906 - Promoted to Corporal for the **2nd Battery**

Is that normal? To go back to the previous Battery when you are promoted? Anything is possible I guess!

Then then that aforementioned text says:

> Por disposición
> del Sr. Coronel 1er Jefe de la Comandancia de 27 de Enero tomó la
> denominación de **1a Batería** --- a que pertenece el individuo contenido
> en esta filiación.

The original text was discussed [here](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39397/28260). I just don't understand this reference to the **1st Battery**.

Comment: Hi Andrew, why not to continue the discussion in the original post? To answer to your question, what I understand is that the 27th of January the 2nd Battery became the 1st Battery by decision of the Sr Coronel.

Comment: @SergioVelasquez Sorry for any confusion. I thought it best to ask distinct question because the linked question was specific to a single note and I did not want to complicate that discussion with other notes.

Comment: I think this is a question more for History Stack Exchange than for Spanish Language.