# Difficulty translating Spanish text from an entry for 1906/1907 in Civil Guard records

Tags: identificación-de-término

I want to confirm the remaining 1906 / 1907 entries in these Civil Guard notes for my Great Grandfather before I go back to discuss the 194 notes.

---

### 1906 (continued)

The handwriting has now changed because my Great Grandfather is now working for the Civil Guard instead of the Military in Mallorca. For the most part I think the text is quite clear but there are some words I am not sure of:

[image]

> En 1o de Sepbré y procedente de la Commanda de Artillería de xxx
> xxx, causo alta en la Commandaucia de la Guía Civil de Sevilla en
> clase de guardia segundo de Infantería por el tiempo de cuatro años,
> según Circular del Excmo. Sr. Director xxx del Cuerpo fecha 22 de
> Agosto inserto en D. O. numero 181. Enterado y Conforme firma la
> presente nota con el jefe y testigos que xxx en Palma de Mallorca a 17
> de Sepbré de 1906. El interesado – Miguel Torres Jiménez - El Guía 2o
> Guillermo xxx xxx - El Cabo Monserrate Galmes Nadal – El jefe del
> Detall Pedro Gil Carrió. El 2o Jefe

Most of the unknown words are to do with names I think but there also be some typos I have made in the transcribing.

There is just one word that I can't decipher in the next entry for 1906:

[image]

So far I have:

> El 5 de Octubre se XXX al puerto de Herrera para prestar el servicio
> de en clase al que fue destinado por orden del Señor 1er Jefe de la
> Comandancia.

The final note for 1906, and that of 1907 are quite clear:

[image]

> Termino el año prestando el servicio de su clase en el puerto de Herrera.

[image]

> Todo el año prestando el servicio de su clase en el puerto de Herrera.

I have observations about these notes:

1. The style of writing seems to be different now because the previous notes were in the *third person*. But these latter notes use the term "su" which I believe means "you" in English. Correct?
2. I can't see a **Puerto de Herrera** on the maps and a puerto (port) does not make sense given the location of **Herrera** itself. I notice near by there is a **Puente Genil** (which is referred to in the 1930 notes). So clarification about this location is appreciated.

#### Update about Herrera

I found the official contact page:

[Puesto De Herrera](https://www.guardiacivil.es/es/institucional/directorio/sevilla/puesto_de_herrera.html)

---

### Translations

Using the suggested text in the answer received I have come up with the following translations:

> On the 1st of September and coming from the Artillery Command of
> Menorca, he was commissioned in the Commandery of the Civil Guide of
> Seville in the class of second Infantry guard for a period of four
> years, according to Circular of the Excellency Mr. General Director of
> the Corps dated the 22nd of August inserted in D. O. number 181.
> Having been informed and in accordance, he signs this note with the
> undersigned chief and witnesses in Palma de Mallorca on the 17th of
> September 1906. The interested party - Miguel Torres Jiménez - The 2nd
> Guide Guillermo Montaner González - Corporal Monserrate Galmes Nadal -
> The head of the Detail Pedro Gil Carrió.

And:

> On 5 October he joined the Herrera post to perform the service of his
> class to which he was assigned by order of the 1st Chief of the
> Command.

And the other two:

- He finished the year serving in his class at the Herrera post.
- All year round, providing the service of his class at the Herrera post.

---

### Related questions

- [Difficulty translating Spanish text from an entry for 1930 in Civil Guard records](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39375/28260)
- [Transcribing Spanish text (Title) of Civil Guard document and deciphering Job Title](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39379/28260)
- [Transcribing the various Assignments that my Great Grandfather had (as listed on his Civil Guard records)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39382/28260)
- [Difficulty translating Spanish text from an entry for 1905 in Civil Guard records](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39387/28260)
- [Difficulty translating Spanish text from an entry for 1906 in Civil Guard records](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39397/28260)
- [Difficulty translating Spanish text from an entry for 1906/1907 in Civil Guard records](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39402/28260)
- [Difficulty translating Spanish text for remaining 1904 entries in Civil Guard records](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39411/28260)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me offer you some suggestions

> En 1º de Sepbré (Septiembre) y procedente de la Comandª (**Comandancia**) de Artillería de **Menorca**,
> causo alta en la **Comandancia** de la Guía (Guardia) Civil de Sevilla en clase de
> guardia segundo de Infantería por el tiempo de cuatro años, según
> Circular del Excmo. Sr. Director Gnal. (**General**) del Cuerpo fecha 22 de Agosto
> inserto en D. O. numero 181. Enterado y Conforme firma la presente
> nota con el jefe y testigos que **suscriben** en Palma de Mallorca a 17 de
> Sepbre de 1906. El interesado – Miguel Torres Jiménez - El Guía 2o
> Guillermo **Montaner González** - El Cabo Monserrate Galmes Nadal – El jefe del
> Detall Pedro Gil Carrió. El 2o Jefe

---

The word that you're missing here is: **incorporó**. And you have misinterpreted **puerto**, that's the reason that you can't find a town named Puerto de Herrera. In this case, the correct word is **puesto**

> El 5 de Octubre se **incorporó** al **puesto** de Herrera para prestar el servicio
> de **su** clase al que fue destinado por orden del Señor 1er Jefe de la
> Comandancia.

[**Puesto**](https://dle.rae.es/puesto) means in this context

> 8. m. Destacamento permanente de Guardia Civil o de carabineros cuyo jefe inmediato tiene grado inferior al de oficial.

In the case of the Guardia Civil, **puesto** usually means both the military unit and the building where such unit is located. In this second acception is a kind of special **police station** of the Guardia Civil located in small towns.

According to the Oxford Dictionary, we can use the third acception of **[post](https://www.lexico.com/definition/post)** to translate puesto, as you can see below it's almost a perfect match

**post**

> 2A place where someone is on duty or where a particular activity is
> carried out.
> 2.1 A place where a soldier or police officer is stationed or which they patrol.

The town where your great grandfather served probably is [**Herrera**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herrera_(Sevilla)), in the province of Seville, as you have mentioned.

---

**Su** is not a pronoun, it's a possesive adjective that can be translated as **his**. The third person remains. I don't observe the change in style that you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions and explanations about the places. I really appreciate your help. Even though I am half Spanish I don't have the knowledge of the grammar etc. In the translations that I added to my question DeepL has settled on "post". But based on your comments here I should change that word to police station.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle After consulting the Oxford Dictionary, I support DeepL option: "post". I've updated my answer accordingly.