# Difficulty translating Spanish text from an entry for 1908 in Civil Guard records

Tags: identificación-de-término

I am looking at this entry for 1908 for my Great Grandfathers Civil Guard history:

[image]

I have transcribed it so far like this:

> 1908: Por Real Orden de 14 de Marzo fecha, trasladada por el **Excmo. Sr.** **Gobernador**
> Civil de la provincia con fecha 17 del mismo, recibió las gracias de
> S. M. el Rey (q. D. g.) por el interés demostrado en todos los
> servicios que se le comandancia durante la permanecía en Sevilla de la
> familia Real. El 2o Jefe

I am assuming that the abbreviation **E. S.** means **Excmo. Señor**? And I can't make out the following word. It does not look like **Commander**.

At the moment I have the following translation:

> 1908: By Royal Order dated 14th March, transferred by **His Excellency** the Civil **Governor** of the province on the 17th of the same month, he received the
> thanks of H. M. the King (q. D. g.) for the interest shown in all the
> services that he commanded during the stay of the Royal family in
> Seville. The 2nd Chief

I know that **q. D. g.** means **que Dios guarde**. From my research that means something like **may God bless you**. Right?

It's kind of exciting for mean to come across information like this. :)

---

### Update 1

I think I have worked it out:

- Gobernador

I have updated the text above in **bold**. Any confirmation about **d. D. g.** or any other thoughts welcome.

---

### Related Questions

- [Difficulty translating Spanish text from an entry for 1930 in Civil Guard records](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39375/28260)
- [Transcribing Spanish text (Title) of Civil Guard document and deciphering Job Title](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39379/28260)
- [Transcribing the various Assignments that my Great Grandfather had (as listed on his Civil Guard records)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39382/28260)
- [Difficulty translating Spanish text from an entry for 1905 in Civil Guard records](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39387/28260)
- [Difficulty translating Spanish text from an entry for 1906 in Civil Guard records](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39397/28260)
- [Difficulty translating Spanish text from an entry for 1906/1907 in Civil Guard records](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39402/28260)
- [Difficulty translating Spanish text for remaining 1904 entries in Civil Guard records](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39411/28260)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me make a minimal amendment

> 1908: Por Real Orden de 14 de Marzo fecha, trasladada por el Excmo.
> Sr. Gobernador Civil de la provincia con fecha 17 del mismo, recibió
> las gracias de S. M. el Rey (q. D. g.) por el interés demostrado en
> todos los servicios que se le **encomendaron** durante la **permanencia** en
> Sevilla de la Familia Real. El 2o Jefe

---

You're right q.D.g stands for **que Dios guarde**. It can be translated as "God **save** him" instead of "God **bless** him" (In Spanish, *Dios le bendiga*). Though such expression can be applied to anyone, I think that in this context is near to the sense described in the Wikipedia entry associated to the expression **God save the King/Queen**.

> An expression of one’s patriotism and hope for the long life of the
> monarch, especially in his presence.

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications. I also wonder if the word **demostrado** should be translated as **demonstrated** instead of **shown**.