# Difficulty translating Spanish text from an entry for 1904 in Civil Guard records

Tags: identificación-de-término

My ongoing transcribing and translation of my Great Grandfathers Civil Guard records continues.

At the moment I have gone back to the 1904 notes. I want to review one of them by itself.

Here it is:

[image]

As you can see, some of the text is tricky to read so I have a lot of gaps and I know I have made errors too. This is what I have so far:

> En la revista del mes actual y con fecha 3 del mes anterior pase xxx
> este xxx en la 2o compañía de este segundo batallón de artillería de
> plaza procedente de la xxx Militar de Osuna no 10 en virtud de lo xxx
> en R. O. C. de 13 Febrero último (D. O. no 33) xxx el día 3 de la
> partida recejotora y presentianolose oí Banderas el 3 del citado mes.
> Reconoció por la xxx del Batallón resulto utel para el servicio de las
> armas fue vacunado y confrontada esta filiación con el interesado
> resulto efecto. Tallado tuvo 1'680 metro de estatura y 60 kg de peso.
>
> Cádiz 6 Abril 1904
>
> El Comandante Mayor

The first task as usual is to get the transcribed text as best as possible so that I can try to translate it.

But the second task relates to the [D.O. no 33](http://www.bibliotecavirtualdefensa.es/BVMDefensa/es/catalogo_imagenes/grupo.do?path=6792). I am not sure if my actual Great Grandfather Miguel Torres Jimenez should be mentioned but I can't find him. And since I am not yet sure of the correct transcription etc. I am not clear as to which part of this bulletin we are referring to.

I think I have the right bulletin.

---

### Translation

> In the review of the current month and dated the 3rd of the previous
> month, this individual was discharged into the 2nd company of this
> second battalion of artillery from the Military Zone of Osuna nº 10 by
> virtue of the provisions of the R. O. C. of the 13th February last (D.
> O. nº 33), joining the receiving party on the 3rd and presenting
> himself to the Flags on the 3rd of the aforementioned month. He was
> examined by the Battalion doctor and found to be fit for armed
> service. He was vaccinated and, when confronted with the person
> concerned, this information proved to be exact. He was 1'680 m tall
> and weighed 60 kg.

I get confused by way that DeepL is translating words as **discharged** etc.

---

### Related Questions

- [Difficulty translating Spanish text from an entry for 1930 in Civil Guard records](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39375/28260)
- [Transcribing Spanish text (Title) of Civil Guard document and deciphering Job Title](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39379/28260)
- [Transcribing the various Assignments that my Great Grandfather had (as listed on his Civil Guard records)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39382/28260)
- [Difficulty translating Spanish text from an entry for 1905 in Civil Guard records](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39387/28260)
- [Difficulty translating Spanish text from an entry for 1906 in Civil Guard records](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39397/28260)
- [Difficulty translating Spanish text from an entry for 1906/1907 in Civil Guard records](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39402/28260)
- [Difficulty translating Spanish text from an entry for 1908 in Civil Guard records](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39404/28260)
- [Difficulty translating Spanish text for remaining 1904 entries in Civil Guard records](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39411/28260)

Comment: The text is not so difficult. Deciphering the handwriting is.

Comment: @Lambie For me that is not the case. Perhaps it is my colour-blindness. The printed text doesn't standout very well from the background for me personally.

Comment: That is what I am saying. You say the printed text doesn't stand out. That's right. It's faded and hard to read. But the language is not hard to understand once one actually has the text in hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestions in bold

> En la revista del mes actual y con fecha 3 del mes anterior **dase alta**
> este **individuo** en la 2ª compañía de este segundo batallón de artillería de
> plaza procedente de la **Zona** Militar de Osuna nº 10 en virtud de lo **dispuesto**
> en R. O. C. de 13 Febrero último (D. O. nº 33) **incorporándose** el día 3 **a** la
> partida **receptora** y **presentándose** **a** Banderas el 3 del citado mes.
> **Reconocido por el médico** del Batallón resultó **útil** para el servicio de las
> armas fue vacunado y confrontada esta filiación con el interesado
> resulto **exacta**. Tallado tuvo 1'680 metro de estatura y 60 kg de peso.
>
> Cádiz 6 Abril 1904
>
> El Comandante Mayor

I've checked the linked bulletin and I don't think that your ancestor's name should be specifically mentioned. It shows the general dispositions for the new recruits, how many of them are destinated to each unit. Probably your ancestor is included here in the line **2º Bón. Art. de Plaza** mentioned in the **Osuna** zone. (page 20 of the pdf document)

[image]

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. I will try this shortly and provide a translation for review. So my basic understanding is that he has moved from Osuna unit to Cadiz unit.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle I think that he was not transferred, he was RECRUITED in the zone of Osuna. Do you know where he was born or where he was living at that time? Such data could back my guessing up.

Comment: I will be raising a question separately about his "movements" between the sites. From page 1 I know he was born in Saucejo / Osuna / Sevilla. And I am attempting to obtain his birth certificate.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle There you are. He was born in El Saucejo, that was part of the military zone of Osuna, both towns located in the province of Seville. Also, I think that you have nailed the translation this time.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle No suggestions this time. I think it's very good.

Comment: Quick question. In the bulletin, does he fall in the left column or right column? I assume one column is for those leaving the site and the other column for those going to the site.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle The columns are labeled "Número total de reclutas que incorporaría desde luego" (LEFT) and "Número total de reclutas que se señala" (RIGHT), both under "CUERPOS QUE SACAN DE CADA UNA" meaning "Units that receive from each (zone)". I don't know the difference between those columns. "desde luego" does not make any sense for me, the time of incorporation is not clear in those to words, they are military jargon, but it seems that all recruits, both quantities, are received in the unit.