# Difficulty translating Spanish text for remaining 1904 entries in Civil Guard records

Tags: identificación-de-término

There are four remaining entries for the year 1904 in the notes for my Great Grandfathers Civil Guard records.

- 8 Abril 1904

[image]

I have so far:

> En el extracto de revista del **corriente** mes **se** le **reclaman a** este
> individuo **cincuenta y seis pesetas** importe de la gratificación de **su**
> [**presente** puesto de **vestuario**].
>
> Cádiz 8 de Abril de 1904
>
> El **Comisario** de Guerra

Note that there is also a stamp showing with the above note:

[image]

- 10 Abril 1904

[image]

I appreciate that some of those words are quite blurry. I have so far:

> En el día de la fecha **prestó** este individuo el **juramento de fidelidad**
> a **la bandera** xxx xxx de este Batallón.
>
> Cádiz 10 de Abril de 1904
>
> El Comandante Mayor

- 28 Agosto 1904

[image]

So far I have:

> 1904: En la misma situación hasta **fin del actual** que **causará** baja en
> este 2o Batallón Artillería de Plaza, por pase a la comandancia de
> **guerra** de Menorca, de **nueva** creación, con arreglo a **lo dispuesto** en la
> R. O. de 11 del mes actual (D. O. no 180) haciéndose **constar** que
> durante **su** permanencia en este Cuerpo **ha** observado buena conducta.
>
> Cádiz 28 Agosto de 1904
>
> El Comandante Mayor

I think I have located the correct [D. O. no. 180](http://www.bibliotecavirtualdefensa.es/BVMDefensa/es/catalogo_imagenes/grupo.do?path=6939) bulletin referred to in that note but have not yet isolated the pertinent entry.

- 31 Diciembre 1904

[image]

So far I have:

> 1904: En la revista de Septiembre causó alta el individuo contenido en
> esta filiación en las tropas de Artillería de la Comandancia de
> Menorca, **siendo destinado** a la 2o Batería (Reina Regente). Situación:
> Desde su alta en estas tropas de guon (**guarnición**) en Mahón y
> continúa.  Tallado tuvo de la estatura de 1’683mt.
>
> Mahón 31 de Diciembre 1904
>
> El Tente (**Teniente**) Corel (**Coronel**) Mayor

Once I complete the transcribed text I can move on to translations. Thanks in advance.

---

### Update 1

I have updated the current text with the suggested wording as provided in the answers. And I have proposed the initial translations.

---

### Update 2

I have found this reference to [Reina Regente](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_cruiser_Reina_Regente_(1906)) although it is associated with 1906 and not 1904. There was a predecessor mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_cruiser_Reina_Regente_(1887)) from 1887. Anyway, I don't know if I am going down the wrong path with this.

Can’t be the 1887 ship as the document said it sank.

The other one (1906) was being built over several years. So I am not sure.

---

### Update 3

I wonder if the bulletin note relates to this on page one as it refers to Menorca and Mahón:

[image]

I translated the text:

> The said Archipelago shall be divided into two military governments,
> one comprising the island of Minorca and the other the two islands of
> Majorca, Ibiza, Formentera and Cabrera, headed by Major Generals, who
> shall be at the same time Governors of the towns of Mahon and Palma de
> Majorca respectively, and Sub-Inspectors of the active troops,
> reserves and recruitment in the territory under their command, the
> Governor of Minorca having a Brigadier General, with the status of
> second-in-command, under his command.

So I do believe this is the information related to the note in the records.

---

### Update 4

Further reading about the [Reina Regente](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_cruiser_Reina_Regente_(1887)) (1887) mentions this about her fate:

> On 10 March 1895, Reina Regente sailed from Tangier, Morocco to Cádiz,
> Spain with 420 crew on board under the command of Captain Francisco
> Sanz de Andino. She was never seen again. A severe storm struck the
> Gulf of Cádiz during the time she was passing through it. In the
> following days a search was undertaken in the hope of finding the ship
> somewhere sheltered in an African port. However, wreckage from the
> cruiser started to wash up on the beaches of Tarifa and Algeciras. The
> cruiser had disappeared and had probably sunk somewhere in the Gulf of
> Cádiz with the loss of her entire crew. The current location of the
> ship is still unknown. This incident remains one of the deadliest
> shipwrecks of the Spanish Navy.

This shows us that the ship was associated with Cádiz and given the fact that there was the loss of her entire crew and may well have been the reason, out of respect for the crew lost, that the Battery was named in her honour.

---

### Translations

So far I have the following translations for these notes:

- 8 April 1904

> In the current month's review extract, fifty-six pesetas are claimed
> from this individual for the amount of the gratuity for his [present
> wardrobe position].
>
> Cadiz 8 April 1904
>
> The War Commissioner

- 10 April 1904

> On the day of the date this individual took the oath of allegiance to
> the flag xxx xxx of this Battalion.
>
> Cadiz 10th April 1904
>
> The Major Commander

- 28 August 1904

> 1904: In the same situation until the end of the current month, when
> he will be discharged from this 2nd Battalion Artillery of Military
> Unit, due to his transfer to the newly created war command of Menorca,
> in accordance with the provisions of the R. O. of the 11th of the
> current month (D. O. No 180), it being noted that during his stay in
> this Corps he has observed good conduct.
>
> Cadiz 28 August 1904
>
> The Major Commander

I have yet to identify the pertinent part of the bulletin for the above note.

- 31 December 1904

> In the September review, the individual in this affiliation was
> discharged in the Artillery troops of the Menorca Command, being
> assigned to the 2nd Battery (Reina Regente). Situation: Since his
> discharge in these troops of guon (garrison) in Mahon and continues.
> His measured height was 1.683m.
>
> Mahon 31st December 1904
>
> Tente (Lieutenant) Corel (Colonel) Major

I need to find out what **(Reina Regente)** means.

---

### Related Questions

- [Difficulty translating Spanish text from an entry for 1930 in Civil Guard records](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39375/28260)
- [Transcribing Spanish text (Title) of Civil Guard document and deciphering Job Title](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39379/28260)
- [Transcribing the various Assignments that my Great Grandfather had (as listed on his Civil Guard records)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39382/28260)
- [Difficulty translating Spanish text from an entry for 1905 in Civil Guard records](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39387/28260)
- [Difficulty translating Spanish text from an entry for 1906 in Civil Guard records](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39397/28260)
- [Difficulty translating Spanish text from an entry for 1906/1907 in Civil Guard records](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39402/28260)
- [Difficulty translating Spanish text from an entry for 1908 in Civil Guard records](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39404/28260)
- [Difficulty translating Spanish text from an entry for 1904 in Civil Guard records](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39406/28260)

Comment: If you don't face limits posting questions I suggest asking a different question about each different image.

Comment: @freethinker36. I don’t think anyone is exempt from restrictions on number of questions asked. Ideally all of my questions should be limited to one note. But in this case I felt it best to combine the four together.

Comment: I think **(Reina Regente)** means **(Queen Regent)**. But I am not sure of its significance. It is the first time it has been associated with a Battery in the records.

Comment: You're right. Reina Regente means Queen Regent. I don't find it so strange for a battery or a battalion or a unit to be named after a King/Queen. In a quick search I've found the 5th Battalion Norfolk Regiment  whose company C where at some point named "King's Company". In Spain, around the same time of your entries, it existed a unit called "Regimiento de Infantería Borbón nº 17" being the Bourbon family the reigning dinasty at that time (until present days).

Comment: So do you think it is not associated with that ship they were building with that name? Or coincidence?

Comment: I don't think so. Multiple elements can be named after the same royal person. I can't see a direct link between the ship that sunk in Cádiz and the battery located in Menorca.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try to improve a bit your transcriptions.

- 8 Abril 1904

I agree with the first part of @freethinker's suggestion.

> En el extracto de revista del corriente mes se le reclaman a este
> individuo cincuenta y seis pesetas importe de la gratificación de su
> [illegible for me].
>
> Cádiz 8 de Abril de 1904.
>
> El **Comisario** de Guerra

La **Comisaría** de Guerra (stamp) is the organism, the Comisario is the chief in that organization and the one that signs the entry.

- 10 Abril 1904

> En el día de la fecha **prestó** este individuo el **juramento de fidelidad** a **la bandera** xxx xxx de este Batallón.
>
> Cádiz 10 de Abril de 1904
>
> El Comandante Mayor

- 28 Agosto 1904

> En la misma situación hasta **fin del actual** que **causará** baja en este
> 2º Batallón Artillería de Plaza, por pase a la comandancia de **guerra** de
> Menorca, de **nueva** creación, con arreglo a **lo dispuesto** en la R. O. de 11 del
> mes actual (D. O. nº 180) haciéndose **constar** que durante **su**
> permanencia en este Cuerpo **ha** observado buena conducta.
>
> Cádiz 28 Agosto de 1904
>
> El Comandante Mayor

hasta **fin del actual** = *until the end of the current (month)*

- 31 Diciembre 1904

> En la revista de Septiembre causó alta el individuo contenido en esta
> filiación en las tropas de Artillería de la Comandancia de Menorca,
> **siendo destinado** a la 2ª Batería (Reina Regente). Situación: Desde su alta en
> estas tropas de guon (**guarnición**) en Mahón y continúa. Tallado tuvo de la estatura
> de 1’683mt.
>
> Mahón 31 de Diciembre 1904
>
> El Tente (**Teniente**) Corel (**Coronel**) Mayor

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I have incorporated everything into the question and added initial translations.

Comment: I wonder if a better translation for **Plaza** should be **Barracks**, rather than **Military Unit**.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle I don't think so, in Spanish we've got a specific translation for barracks: barracones. As you can see both words share the same root. And I don't know if "Military Unit" is used to designate the place where the unit is located.

Comment: I updated my question with my research about the bulletin and the ship. I was not sure if I should have added additional answer with that info.

Answer (score 1):

En el extracto de revista del **corriente** mes **se** le **reclaman a** este individuo **cincuenta y seis** **pesetas** importe de la gratificación de **su** **presente** puesto de **vestuario**.

Cádiz 8 de Abril de 1904.

El **Comisario** de Guerra

Comment: Thanks for your answer about the first note. I will update my question later with your suggestions. Note that i added a screenshot of the stamp which shows **Comisaria**.

Comment: @RubioRic has explained why **Comisario** is correct. So please disregard my previous comment.