# Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1930

Tags: identificación-de-término

There are two notes for 1930 in my great-grandfathers Civil Guard records and we already processed the [first one](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39375/28260).

This is the second one which is typed text:

[image]

As a side point, I now notice that word **Años** in the top left clearly!

At the moment I have this transcribed text:

> Publicado el compromiso anterior en el B. O. del Cuerpo 31 del Nobre.
>
> El Excmo Sr. Ministro del Ejército en R. O. comunicada de fecha 19 de
> Diciembre, trasladada por el Excmo. Sr. Director General del Cuerpo en
> escrito no. 802 de 24 del mismo, manifiesta que S. M. el Rey (q. D.
> g.) ha tenido a bien disponer se den las gracias a este individuo por
> su valor y alto espíritu demostrado en defensa del orden público, así
> como la disciplina, lealtad y abnegación que ha evidenciado en cuantas
> ocasiones se ha visto precisado a intervenir en los tristes sucesos
> acaecidos en el referido mes; y prestando los servicios de su clase en
> el Puesta de Puente Genil.
>
> Fin el año.
>
> El Comandante Mayor

This is the translation:

> Previous commitment published in the B. O. of Corps 31 November.
>
> His Excellency the Minister of the Army in a communicated Order dated
> 19 December, transferred by His Excellency the Director General of the
> Corps in letter no. 802 of 24 December. 802 of the 24th of the same,
> states that His Majesty the King (q.D.g.) has seen fit to order that
> thanks be given to this individual for his courage and high spirit
> shown in defence of public order, as well as the discipline, loyalty
> and self-sacrifice he has shown on all the occasions he has been
> required to intervene in the sad events which occurred during the
> month in question; and providing the services of his class at the
> Puente Genil post.
>
> End of the year.
>
> The Major Commander

My translation using DeepL has messed up again. So I appreciate clarification to both the transcribed text (some words are feint) and the translation.

I see no references to bulletins that we can research this time. I see it says *the sad events which occurred during the month in question* which I think must refer to November 1930. But I am not sure of the circumstances.

Comment: I don't understand how after tons of these questions, anyone is learning Spanish per se. You might want to try this: https://readcoop.eu/transkribus/

Comment: @Lambie We are nearly finished. One or two more notes I think. And I know that others have found this interesting to do. Either way, I have been very grateful for those that have taken the time to help me. It has meant a lot. And I am very grateful to the person who suggested I use this stack exchange platform. But, with being so close to the end, why stop now? Anyway, thanks for your link and I hear you.

Comment: @Lambie I hope that Andrew is learning a bit of Spanish. And some of us discovered the verb finir in these notes. ;-P

Comment: @RubioRic One verb in 20 or more notes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the transcription you've got "Puesta" and it should be "Puest**o**".

In relation with the traslation, as you stated, DeepL seems to messed up some words and lost another ones.

> Previous commitment published in the B. O. of Corps 31 November.
>
> His Excellency the Minister of the Army in a communicated **Royal** Order dated
> 19 December, **transmitted** by His Excellency the Director General of the
> Corps in letter no. 802 of 24 December. 802 of the 24th of the same,
> states that His Majesty the King (**G.s.h**) has seen fit to order that
> thanks be given to this individual for his courage and high spirit
> shown in defence of public order, as well as the discipline, loyalty
> and self-sacrifice he has shown on all the occasions he has been
> required to intervene in the sad events which occurred during the
> month in question; and providing the services of his class at the
> Puente Genil post.
>
> End of the year.
>
> The Major Commander

**R.O** stands for **Real Orden**, DeepL has dropped the R.

**q.D.g** stands for **que Dios guarde**. The equivalent in English it's **God save him**.

I think that **transmitted** is more idiomatic in English than **transferred** in this context.

Apart from the highlighted parts, the text seems ok to me. Which other words do you think that are feint?

---

I can't find any specific information about what happened in Puente Genil at that time but the [Jaca Uprising](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaca_uprising) took place in December 12th 1930. That event was part of a planned nation-wide uprising against the current dictatorship and the monarchy but apart from part of the Jaca garrison the movement was not seconded in the rest of the country. The events that occurred in Puente Genil may be related with the uprising or be protests againts the execution of Galán and García Hernández a few days later.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and updated translation. You have covered everything. I also appreciate the possible link connected to the events. One point: it clearly used **fino** in this note so I am hazarding a guess the possibly all of them did? Although, *Fino el ano* does not translate well. :)

Comment: @AndrewTruckle As we have discussed, finar means to die, there is no doubt about that. The verb finalizar (to finish, to end) doesn't have that verb tense. It's a typo or a repeated grammatical error. You can transcript that word as finó adding a (sic) after it if you like.

Comment: No. I agree it to be a typo. Thanks.